# jupyter notebook vs jupyter console: display of markdown (and latex, html, etc) objects

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, sage

i would like to be able to run a jupyter notebook as a regular python file (using a standard python interpreter) as
well. the problem i'm facing is that in python i can not render markdown objects in a usable from:

running the code below renders as it should in the notebook but prints `<IPython.core.display.Markdown object>` in the
when run using just python.

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
display(Markdown('# Hello World!'))
```

i was trying to come up with a way to make that work and found this ugly work-around:

```
from IPython.display import Markdown, display
from IPython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.displaypub import DisplayPublisher
from ipykernel.zmqshell import ZMQDisplayPublisher

display_pub_class = get_ipython().display_pub_class()

def displaymd(strg):
    if isinstance(display_pub_class, ZMQDisplayPublisher):
        display(Markdown(strg))
    elif isinstance(display_pub_class, DisplayPublisher):
        print(strg)
    else:
        # ??
        display(strg)

displaymd('# Hello World!')
```

that seems very hacky! is there a simpler way to get a reasonable `display` of markdown objects? or at least a simpler way to know whether `display` is capable of rendering markdown?

the same question goes for latex, html and similar objects.

---

just found out a silghtly simpler way to check if i am on ipython:

```
def on_ipython():
    if 'get_ipython' in globals():
        return True
    else:
        return False

def displaymd(strg):
    if on_ipython():
        display(Markdown(strg))
    else:
        print(strg)
```

still this is not very nice...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Option 1: dicts with both 'text/plain' and 'text/markdown' entries

You can pass a dict containing different MIME types to IPython's `display(..., raw=True)`: Jupyter Notebook will use the rich representation, and an IPython or plain Python frontend will fall back to the `text/plain` representation.

Here's a minimal complete example; try running it in an IPython terminal and in a Jupyter notebook, and you'll see it renders properly in both.

```
from IPython.display import display


my_markdown_string = '''\
# Heading one

This is

* a
* list
'''

display({'text/plain': my_markdown_string,
         'text/markdown': my_markdown_string},
        raw=True)
```

### Option 2: Define a custom text/plain formatter for objects of class Markdown

Example is based on the 'define a new `int` formatter' example from the IPython [`display`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.display.html#IPython.display.display) docs. You'll want to run it in IPython to see its effect.

```
from IPython.display import display, Markdown

def md_formatter(md, pp, cycle):
    pp.text(md.data)

text_plain = get_ipython().display_formatter.formatters['text/plain']
text_plain.for_type(Markdown, md_formatter)

display(Markdown('x **x** x'))
# x **x** x

del text_plain.type_printers[Markdown]
display(Markdown('x **x** x'))
# <IPython.core.display.Markdown object>
```

### Appendix: list of MIME types Jupyter/IPython knows about

Taken from the [DisplayFormatter](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/generated/IPython.core.formatters.html?highlight=text%2Flatex#IPython.core.formatters.DisplayFormatter) docs:

> See the [`display_data` message](https://jupyter-client.readthedocs.io/en/latest/messaging.html#display-data) in the messaging documentation for
>   more details about this message type.
>
> The following MIME types are currently implemented:
>
> - text/plain
> - text/html
> - text/markdown
> - text/latex
> - application/json
> - application/javascript
> - image/png
> - image/jpeg
> - image/svg+xml